# URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl() returns VF Subdomain URL

Tags: visualforce, rest-api, callout

I'm on doing custom logs, there for I use an internal REST callout to bypass a LimitException rollback.

My page:

> c.na15.visual.force.com/apex/TestPage

Controller code:

```
.
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setHeader( 'Authorization', 'OAuth '+UserInfo.getSessionId() );
    req.setEndpoint( URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() );
.
```

like you see, I'm trying to get the server url,

> na15.salesforce.com

but what URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl() returns is the VF Subdomain URL

> c.na15.visual.force.com

This is a known problem, but I'm not able to find a useful solution.
Bad practice that I actually use to solve it:

```
String salesforceHost = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm().replace('visual.','sales').replace('c.na','na');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should return what you want:

```
private String instanceUrl() {
    String result = null;

    List<String> fragments = URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().split('\\.');

    if(fragments.size() == 3) {
        result = fragments[0]; // Note: Apex URL: NA14.salesforce.com
    }
    else if(fragments.size() == 5) {
        result = fragments[1]; // Note: Visualforce URL: mydomain.NA14.visual.force.com
    }

    return result + '.salesforce.com';
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little more explanation around what fragments you see and why the numbers `3` and `5` are significant?

Answer (score 3):

Visualforce is served from a [different subdomain to prevent Cross Domain Scripting attacks](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Visualforce-Development/Please-explain-cs2-salesforce-com-vs-c-cs2-salesforce-com/td-p/110601) and  other security reasons. Therefore URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() in a VF Context returns the subdomain URL (its not the VF Page, rather the VF Subdomain URL)

I'd imagine what you've done is possibly the best work around.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could build your required URL using the InstanceName from the Organization object such as:

select InstanceName from Organization

This returns something like NA17 or AP1 etc.

Unlike using 'System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost()' this works in:

Case 1: Any Development Org
Case 2: My Domain Enabled
Case 3: Sandbox
Case 4: Managed Package